# Embedded resources in another file

Tags: resources

the title may be a little misleading, but here is my actual representation of "Embedded resources in another file (than the executable)":

So I have my own file extension (.ffrh) that is basically a "WinRAR". I store my "virtual" folders and files in that file and I access these folders/files through my program to gain access to "application resources". This is where I store my images, fonts, localization files, database files etc.

Now, is it wrong or right to:

Store the data first, before starting/booting the application and use logic if a file is corrupted/outdated etc.

Or

Just open the .ffrh(s) and when resources are demanded by some controls, search the entire file for each demand.

It sounds to me that the first method risks more memory for better performance and the second method does vice versa (lower performance, better memory).

Which method is better to use or that depends on the application?

Comment: "it depends" is probably the right answer. A reasonable compromise might be to read the index into memory and use memory-mapped file access for the resources themselves.

Comment: Yes, I've done the storing the byte arrays from the files into a dictionary (string, byte[]), but that is the first method. Some applications does the same thing that my app tries, but I can't put my finger on it, it seems that my app is using a LOT of memory when storing the entire files/folders, instead of just the byte arrays.

Comment: I want to hear an opinion on the second method. Has anyone tried it? What did it look like? Did it take a lot of time to search the demands?